# How to convert native JS array of CLR types to CLR array with Clearscript

Tags: javascript, c#, type-conversion, clr, clearscript

I'm looking at converting our application from using [JavaScript.NET](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=javascriptdotnet) (Noesis) to use ClearScript.

Our app contains a large number of user-created Javascript algorithms/expressions for financial calculations - **I'd rather avoid having to change those if possible**.

Currently with JavaScript.NET many of the user-defined algorithms follow a pattern of creating a JavaScript array containing host types and passing that as a parameter to a function on another host type. With JavaScript.NET that conversion "just works". See code below for what I'm trying to do:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ClearScript;
using Microsoft.ClearScript.V8;

namespace ClearscriptPlayground
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var engine = new V8ScriptEngine())

            {
                var myClass = new MyClass();;
                engine.AddHostObject("instance", myClass);
                engine.AddHostType("MyType", HostItemFlags.DirectAccess, typeof(MyType));
                engine.Execute(
                        @"var params = [new MyType('bye', 10), 
                                        new MyType('hello', 10)];

                          instance.SomethingElse(params)");

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
//        public void SomethingElse(ITypedArray<MyType> foo)
//        {
//            // Doesn't work.
//        }

//        public void SomethingElse(MyType[] foo)
//        {
//            // Doesn't work.
//        }

//        public void SomethingElse(dynamic foo)
//        {
//            var mapped = foo as ITypedArray<MyType>; // Doesn't work
//            var mapped = foo as MyType[]; // Doesn't work either   
//        }

        public void SomethingElse(ScriptObject foo)
        {
            // Works, but how best to convert to MyType[] or similar?
        }
    }

    public struct MyType
    {
        public string Foo;
        public int Bar;

        public MyType(string foo, int bar)
        {
            Foo = foo;
            Bar = bar;
        }
    }
}
```

**NB**: I know that I can create a host array using `params = host.newArr(MyType, 2);` and that will work - but that would mean modifying all the user-maintained JavaScript which I'd really rather avoid.

Comment: JavaScript.NET is an CLR interface to Google's V8 JavaScript engine (https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net/wiki). ClearScript is an alternative library doing much the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript array directly via `dynamic`:

```
public void SomethingElse(dynamic foo)
{
    var length = foo.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        var my = (MyType)foo[i];
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", my.Foo, my.Bar);
    }
}
```